# Unable to get loaded configuration after log4j2 initialization

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I have a created a `log4j2` configuration file and before initializing it, there is a `LoggerContext` which already exists in the application. I am stopping it and starting the initialization. I am trying to load the configuration file as shown below, but I am unable to see loaded configuration and `FileAppender`, `ConsoleAppender`. It returns `DefaultConfiguration` and existing `LoggerContext`.
I have tried multiple ways to stop the existing `LoggerContext` like `LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(true); context.stop();` but it doesn't seem to work and configuration isn't loaded. I am using log4j 2.17.1.

```
    LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(true);
    Configurator.shutdown(context);
    try {
      uri = new URI(getResourceFromBundle("org.example.loggingframework", "resources/iceLog4j2.xml").toString());   
      InputStream is = new FileInputStream(uri.getPath());
      ConfigurationSource source = new ConfigurationSource(is);
      LoggerContext ctx = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(true);
      ctx.stop();
      Configuration config = ConfigurationFactory.getInstance().getConfiguration(ctx, source);
      ctx.start(config);
      LoggerContext loggerContext = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(true);
      catch (URISyntaxException | IOException e) {     
      e.printStackTrace();     
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of errors in your code:

1. You are retrieving the wrong context: `LogManager.getContext(true)` is equivalent to [`LogManager.getContext()`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/LogManager.html#getContext--), which has a nice warning in its Javadoc:

   > WARNING - The `LoggerContext` returned by this method may not be the `LoggerContext` used to create a `Logger` for the calling class.

   Use `LogManager.getContext(false)` instead, unless you know what you are doing.
2. Your create a `Configuration` object, but you don't use it. Call

   ```java
   context.reconfigure(config);
   ```
3. Stopping and starting the same context again is not really necessary. You can reconfigure a running context.

**Remark:** Your code can be replaced by a simple:

```java
Configurator.reconfigure(uri);
```

(see [Javadoc](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/Configurator.html#reconfigure-java.net.URI-)).